# I need to create a dummy variable between two dates equal to 1

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following kind of data:

```
group<-as.character(c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"))
rain_start<-c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
rain_end<-c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0)
day<-c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(group,rain_start,rain_end,day))
```

which produces:

```
+--------+-------------+-----------+-----+--+
|        |             |           |     |  |
+--------+-------------+-----------+-----+--+
| group  | rain_start  | rain_end  | day |  |
| A      | 1           | 0         | 1   |  |
| A      | 0           | 0         | 2   |  |
| A      | 0           | 1         | 3   |  |
| A      | 0           | 0         | 4   |  |
| B      | 0           | 0         | 1   |  |
| B      | 1           | 0         | 2   |  |
| B      | 0           | 1         | 3   |  |
| B      | 0           | 0         | 4   |  |
+--------+-------------+-----------+-----+--+
```

Now I'd like, **for each group**, to have one column saying whether it was raining or not. So:

```
rain<-c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0)

data2<-as.data.frame(cbind(group,rain,day))
data2
```

which produces:

```
+-------+------+------+--+--+
| group | rain |  day |  |  |
+-------+------+------+--+--+
| A     |    1 |    1 |  |  |
| A     |    1 |    2 |  |  |
| A     |    1 |    3 |  |  |
| A     |    0 |    4 |  |  |
| B     |    1 |    1 |  |  |
| B     |    1 |    2 |  |  |
| B     |    0 |    3 |  |  |
| B     |    0 |    4 |  |  |
+-------+------+------+--+--+
```

I've tried mutate() and ifelse in dplyr but there's an issue with vector mismatching.

Comment: How do you have 1 in second row if both start and end are zero???

Comment: Just a side note - `as.data.frame(cbind(...` is not great practice as it will convert everything to a `character`. Try `data.frame(group,rain_start...` instead to maintain each column's intended class.

Comment: @Duck - I think the point is to fill between the start and end rows.

Comment: But in the case of B, first row in that group is double zero!

Comment: That makes sense, but I still don't understand why `B`, `1` is a rain day. Rain didn't start or end that day, or start any previous day for that group.

Comment: I guess OP can clarify but yes that seems like a mistake in group B.

Comment: I found a way to create the same output as OP, would it be valid to post it??

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed it. You're absolutely right @Duck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `rain_start` starts at day 1 for group B, you can do this as follows :

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(rain = as.integer(between(row_number(), 
                           match(1, rain_start), match(1, rain_end)))) %>%
  select(group, rain, day)

#  group  rain   day
#  <chr> <int> <dbl>
#1 A         1     1
#2 A         1     2
#3 A         1     3
#4 A         0     4
#5 B         1     1
#6 B         1     2
#7 B         0     3
#8 B         0     4
```

We turn all the values to 1 where the `row_number()` is between first value where `rain_start = 1` and first value where `rain_end = 1`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much. I had no idea about the match command.

Answer (score 1):

Following the valid suggestion from @andrew_reece, here a solution using conditionals and `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code 1
data %>% group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(Rain=ifelse(rain_start==1|rain_end==1,1,NA)) %>%
  fill(Rain,.direction = 'up') %>%
  replace(is.na(.),0)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   group [2]
  group rain_start rain_end   day  Rain
  <fct>      <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A              1        0     1     1
2 A              0        0     2     1
3 A              0        1     3     1
4 A              0        0     4     0
5 B              1        0     1     1
6 B              0        1     2     1
7 B              0        0     3     0
8 B              0        0     4     0
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
data <- structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), rain_start = c(1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), rain_end = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), day = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

For laughs, here's a *data.table* version, which will also allow multiple starts and stops within each group. I'll make a slightly extended dataset to allow this to be tested:

```
group <- rep(c("A","B","C"), c(4,4,8))
rain_start <- c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0)
rain_end <- c(0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1)
day <- sequence(c(4,4,8))

data <- data.frame(group, rain_start, rain_end, day)
```

Then the code for flagging rainy days:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, rain := as.integer(!(cumsum(rain_start) - 
               rleid(rev(cumsum(rev(rain_end)))))), by=group]

#    group rain_start rain_end day rain
# 1:     A          1        0   1    1
# 2:     A          0        0   2    1
# 3:     A          0        1   3    1
# 4:     A          0        0   4    0
# 5:     B          0        0   1    0
# 6:     B          1        1   2    1
# 7:     B          0        0   3    0
# 8:     B          0        0   4    0
# 9:     C          0        0   1    0
#10:     C          1        0   2    1
#11:     C          0        0   3    1
#12:     C          0        1   4    1
#13:     C          0        0   5    0
#14:     C          1        0   6    1
#15:     C          0        0   7    1
#16:     C          0        1   8    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `group_by` and [`group_modify`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_map.html), which iterates over each `rain_state` in each group and toggles whether or not it's raining as values in a new column, `raining`.

```
data %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  group_modify(function(d, grp) {
    rain_state <- 0 
    d$raining <- 0

    for (i in 1:nrow(d)) {

      if (d$rain_start[i] == 1) {
        rain_state <- 1
        d$raining[i] <- 1

      } else if (d$rain_end[i] == 1) {
        rain_state <- 0
        d$raining[i] <- 1

      } else if (rain_state == 1) d$raining[i] <- 1
    }
    return (d %>% select(raining, day))
  })

# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   group [2]
  group raining day  
  <fct>   <dbl> <fct>
1 A           1 1    
2 A           1 2    
3 A           1 3    
4 A           0 4    
5 B           1 1    
6 B           1 2    
7 B           0 3    
8 B           0 4
```

Note: I'm assuming `rain_start` actually has a typo, given your expected output, and that you intended Day 1 of Group B to start rain, like this:

```
rain_start<-c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
do.call("rbind", lapply(split(type.convert(df), df$group), function(x) {
  within(x, rain <- ifelse(rain_end == 1 & rain_start == 1, TRUE,
                      c(as.logical(rain_start[1]), diff(cumsum(rain_start) -
                                    c(0, rain_end[-nrow(x)])) == 0)))
    }
  )
)
```